# Update values in gridview row after data has changed, without invoking a resort via DataBind()

Tags: asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

A page has a gridview bound to a sqldatasource. I don't allow edits in the gridview. Most of it's columns are template fields with label controls. a formview control on the same page shows the data for the currently selected gridview row. Updates are made to the formview control. I want the gridview to reflect the updated data after it has been saved. A simple gv.DataBind() works but the data update can be involved in the gridview's sort, so if I call gv.DataBind() the updated row in gv may end up on some distant page of the grid. I would prefer that the gridview simply update any changed data in the already selected row.

What I've done so far is to have the sub that update the formview also change the text values of the labels on the selected gv row. That seems to work but does not persist. I see the changes in the gv cells, but as soon as I select another row in the gridview, the modified cells in the previously edited row go blank, for some reason.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Get the current page of the gridview (.PageIndex), do a DataBind(), then (re)set the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "(re)set the page"? If I get the current page, do a databind(), the record that was just edited could end up on a completely different page, depending on the column that was updated and the grid sort. If your re set thing helps find that record good. But what I actually want to do is to have just the one row of the gridview to be updated to show the new data without it moving in the gridview...keep it, with updated data, in the same spot.

Comment: I mean reset the page of the gridview. `save the current page of the gridview in a variable`, do your data work, do databind(), if the gridview goes back to page 1, `set the page of the gridview` to page you saved earlier in your variable.

Comment: That wouldn't solve the issue, because after the formview data update, the updated record might not appear on the same gridview page as it was on originally. Example if the gridview is sorted by Last Name and the formview update changes the person's last name from Klunkedorf to Clunkendorf, after the data bind the record would be on a different gv page. Thus my interest in updating the single row's text values...and not rebinding the gv.

Comment: No one has any idea if this is possible or not?